# Unable to access sheet in a method?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**Unresolved reference 'sheet' error happens.**
The code I have tried is below:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, sheet_path):
        self.file = glob.glob(sheet_path)
        self.construction_area ={}

    def read(self):
        for x in self.file:
            if "$" not in x:
                book = xlrd.open_workbook(x)
                sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
                cells = [('user_id', 0, 9),
                             ('name', 4, 0),
                             ('age', 4, 1),]
　　　　　　　　　　・
　　　　　　　　　　・
　　　def save(self):
　　　　　　　　　　・
　　　　　　　　　　・
            for row_index in range(7, sheet.nrows):
                row = sheet.row_values(row_index)
　　　　　　　　　　・
　　　　　　　　　　・
x = User('./data/*.xlsx')
x.read()
x.save()
```

In `sheet` of save method the error happens.I added `self` in front of sheet, but AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'sheet' error happens.
Why can't I access 'sheet' ? Is making instance not enough ? How can I fix this?

Comment: It is right, no sheet attribute for User in above code.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Oh really?So,what should I fix this?

Comment: The only fix you need to do is use self, in save method use self to access sheet. Like self.sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, to access to an instance member, you have to specify the instance, by using the classical `self` keyword from inside the instance.

Your `sheet` variable, is **locally** created in the `read` method, but only locally, it is never attached to the current instance of `User`.
If you need to save these sheet (and it looks like this is what you want ;) ), you'll have to use the `self.sheet` everywhere (and moreover, declare it in the `__init__` method)

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, sheet_path):
        self.file = glob.glob(sheet_path)
        self.construction_area ={}
        self.sheet = None

    def read(self):
        for x in self.file:
            if "$" not in x:
                book = xlrd.open_workbook(x)
                self.sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
                cells = [('user_id', 0, 9),
                         ('name', 4, 0),
                         ('age', 4, 1),]

    def save(self):
        for row_index in range(7, sheet.nrows):
            row = self.sheet.row_values(row_index)
```